# Can't access object contained in other object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

newbie here. I want to show the div with the content only if the 'en' property is different from '...'.
this is the console.log of my currentData:

{title: {…}, text: {…}, learnMoreText: {default: "..."
en: "..."}}

my jsx looks like this:

```
currentData.learnMoreText.en !== '...' ? <div>content</div> : ''
```

I have the error: *Property 'en' does not exist on type 'TStringOrLanguagesObject'.
Property 'en' does not exist on type 'string'.*

```
TStringOrLanguagesObject = string | TLanguagesObject
```

I'm struggling to understand...any help is welcome!

Comment: Change `!==` to `!=`

Comment: same problem...

Comment: You have to check if `learnMoreText` is a string before using it.

Comment: Can you please show us the definition of the `TStringOrLanguagesObject` type?

Comment: @Phillip sure!  type TStringOrLanguagesObject = string | TLanguagesObject;

Comment: @Garth well then make sure that `learnMoreText` is not a string first: `typeof learnMoreText !== 'string'`. As you error message says: the property `en` does not exist on type `string` (and I assume it exists on `TLanguagesObject`)

Comment: Do not forget to update your question per comments. You have added some code in comments and you should update your post. SO users having hard time reading through all comments to figure out what the problem is. Others can benefit from reading clear problem description with the answer marked as solved.

Comment: You showed us `IOnboardingData` not the `TStringOrLanguagesObject`

Comment: @Phillip thanks for the advice, i'll add it immediately!

Comment: Can you share whole component and types please, in this way it is not so clear to understand